# Unable connect WLST to Admin Server

Tags: python, weblogic, jython, weblogic11g, wlst

I new in Weblogic and WLST
I write script connect WLST to Admin Server by Jython but I revecied error when connect.

> WLSTException: Error occured while performing connect : Error getting
>   the initial context. There is no server running at t3://localhost:7001

My Jython code:

```
print '--------------------------------------------------------------------'
print '-- START NODE MANAGER --'
print '--------------------------------------------------------------------'

startNodeManager(verbose='true', NodeManagerHome='C:/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/nodemanager', ListenPort='5556', ListenAddress='localhost')

print '--------------------------------------------------------------------'
print '-- CONNECT WLST TO NODE MANAGER --'
print '--------------------------------------------------------------------'

nmConnect('weblogic', 'abcd123-', 'localhost', '5556', 'base_domain', 'C:/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/base_domain','ssl')

print '--------------------------------------------------------------------'
print '-- START ADMIN SERVER --'
print '--------------------------------------------------------------------'

nmStart('AdminServer')
nmServerStatus('AdminServer')

print '--------------------------------------------------------------------'
print '-- CONNECT WLST TO ADMIN SERVER --'
print '--------------------------------------------------------------------'

connect('weblogic', 'abcd123-')
# connect('weblogic', 'abcd123-', 't3://localhost:7001') I aloso try this but not work
```

Comment: Can you get into the administration console at: http://localhost:7001/console ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Weblogic is not running.

As suggested in the comment, try accessing `http://localhost:7001/console` to verify that the weblogic is running.

Comment: I run startWeblogic.cmd then can access http://localhost:7001/console
I think startWeblogic.cmd is run AdminServer same code nmStart('AdminServer').
How to run startWeblogic.cmd use WLST ?

Comment: I want run just with a file .cmd

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best way is to write a batch file, inside which you can call your Jyhton script.

Sample

```
echo %TIME% Start executing Jython script 
call setWLSEnv.cmd
java weblogic.WLST start_servers.py
echo %TIME% Finished
```